# In MATLAB, using the following function, Why is the classification accuracy (acc1, acc2) calculated differently?

Tags: matlab, classification, cross-validation, knn

The following function (**knn_test**) takes the following parameters: **X** indicates dataset sampels, **Y** indicates dataset labels, and **filterindex** corresponds column filter. If I want to filter the data, filterIndex is set to 1, whichever column is to be filtered. 
I want to validate two holdout method. One with **crossval** function, and the other with **cvpartition** function. But when I call this method, **acc1** and **acc2** variables show different values.

I added break point to the code and debugged the code. I examined CVKNNModels' partition property and it was the same with de c partition in the Model 2.

What could have gone wrong with the following code?

Why did these two accuracy variables take different values?

If I want to use this function for holdout classification, which model should I choose?

Thanks.

```
function [acc1,acc2]=knn_test(X,Y,filterIndex)
columnfilterIndex = find(filterIndex==1);

%Model 1
tra1Data = X(:,[columnfilterIndex]);
tra1Label=Y;
KNNModel1=fitcknn(tra1Data, tra1Label, 'Distance', 'Euclidean', 'NumNeighbors', 3, 'DistanceWeight', 'Equal', 'Standardize', true);
rng('default');
CVKNNModel = crossval(KNNModel1,'holdout',0.3);
loss=kfoldLoss(CVKNNModel);
acc1=1-loss;

%Model 2
rng('default');
c = cvpartition(Y,'HoldOut',0.3);
tra2Data=X(c.training,[columnfilterIndex]);
tra2Label=Y(c.training,:);
test2Data=X(c.test,[columnfilterIndex]);
test2Label=Y(c.test,:);
KNNModel2 = fitcknn(tra2Data,tra2Label,'Distance', 'Euclidean','NumNeighbors',3, 'DistanceWeight', 'Equal','Standardize', true);
pre_test = predict(KNNModel2,test2Data);
correctPredictions = (pre_test == test2Label);
acc2 = sum(correctPredictions)/length(correctPredictions);
%perf=classperf(uint8(test2Label),uint8(pre_test)); 
%acc2=perf.CorrectRate;
```

Comment: You should ask whoever wrote the code....

Comment: I wrote this code. :D

Comment: You are computing acc1 and acc2 differently and they show different values. Where is the surprise then?

Comment: The Same data, the same partitions, different partitioning mechanism (but same randomization seed point, so same sub partition with data, training and test).
It could be the same results.

Comment: But one is `acc1=1-loss;` and the other `acc2 = sum(correctPredictions)/length(correctPredictions);`

Comment: Model 1: computes loss value. Accuracy value is complement to 1 of loss value. so, 2 methods must be calculate same accuracy value.

Comment: Is there any reason to use different functions then?

Comment: Which one is correct value? Which one should I choose? for this reason it is very important.